# Como desenhar uma seta utilizando Java2D?

Tags: java, swing, java2d

Estou tentando desenhar uma seta dentro de um círculo (semelhante a um ponteiro de relógio), mas não estou conseguindo alinhar a ponta da seta com o restante da linha.

Fiz a "flecha" baseado [nesta resposta do SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3094933/5524514), mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que ela fique posicionada corretamente com a linha que desenho.

A ponta da seta fica mais a esquerda da linha, conforme segue na imagem:

[image: Screenshot do relógio]

Segue minha classe `LineArrow`:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class LineArrow {

    int x;
    int y;
    int endX;
    int endY;
    Color color;
    int thickness;

    public LineArrow(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, Color color, int thickness) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.endX = x2;
        this.endY = y2;

        this.color = color;
        this.thickness = thickness;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));
        g2.drawLine(x, y, endX, endY);;
        drawArrowHead(g2);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    private void drawArrowHead(Graphics2D g2) {

        Polygon arrowHead = new Polygon();
        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
        arrowHead.addPoint(0, 5);
        arrowHead.addPoint(-5, -5);
        arrowHead.addPoint(5, -5);

        tx.setToIdentity();
        double angle = Math.atan2(endY - y, endX - x);
        tx.translate(endX, endY);
        tx.rotate(angle - Math.PI / 2d);

        g2.setTransform(tx);
        g2.fill(arrowHead);
    }

}
```

> Obs.: não adicionei código de desenho do círculo pois a classe acima é autossuficiente para simular o problema da imagem.

---

Segue um exemplo:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class LineArrowTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel DrawPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new LineArrowTest().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public LineArrowTest() {
        initComponents();
        pack();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        this.contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        this.contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(this.contentPane);

        this.DrawPanel = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                LineArrow line = new LineArrow(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, getWidth() / 2, getHeight(),
                        Color.black, 3);
                line.draw(g);
            }
        };
        this.contentPane.add(this.DrawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    class LineArrow {

        int x;
        int y;
        int endX;
        int endY;
        Color color;
        int thickness;

        public LineArrow(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, Color color, int thickness) {
            super();
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.endX = x2;
            this.endY = y2;

            this.color = color;
            this.thickness = thickness;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

            g2.setColor(color);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));
            g2.drawLine(x, y, endX, endY);
            ;
            drawArrowHead(g2);
            g2.dispose();
        }

        private void drawArrowHead(Graphics2D g2) {

            Polygon arrowHead = new Polygon();
            AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();

            arrowHead.addPoint(0, 5);
            arrowHead.addPoint(-5, -5);
            arrowHead.addPoint(5, -5);

            tx.setToIdentity();
            double angle = Math.atan2(endY - y, endX - x);
            tx.translate(endX, endY);
            tx.rotate(angle - Math.PI / 2d);

            g2.setTransform(tx);
            g2.fill(arrowHead);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Posso tentar usar uma abordagem usando matriz de rotação... só que fica para mais tarde

Comment: Poste também a classe que faz o `JFrame`, para que eu (ou qualquer outra pessoa que vá tentar responder) não tenha que recodificar ela e também deixar a sua pergunta MCVE.

Comment: Aliás, fiz um teste rápido desenhando a seta dentro de um `JPanel` (sem o círculo vermelho e nem o botão) e ela foi desenhada corretamente. Não mudei uma vírgula do seu código. Testei com a seta de vários tamanhos e para várias direções e funcionou com todas. Assim sendo, poste o que há no restante do código porque o seu problema deve estar em algum outro lugar.

Comment: @VictorStafusa postado.

Comment: A borda do componente está zoando o seu `AffineTransform`. É por isso que não achei o problema quando eu fiz um teste rápido, pois não coloquei borda. No entanto, ainda não achei ainda a solução.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiz algumas mudanças no seu código:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LineArrowTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new LineArrowTest().setVisible(true));
    }

    public LineArrowTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel() {

            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                g.drawRect(0, 0, this.getWidth() - 1, this.getHeight() - 1);
                Insets insets = getInsets();
                LineArrow line1 = new LineArrow(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2, this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight(), Color.BLACK, 3);
                line1.draw(g);
                LineArrow line2 = new LineArrow(20, 40, 60, 80, Color.RED, 3);
                line2.draw(g);
                LineArrow line3 = new LineArrow(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), Color.GREEN, 3);
                line3.draw(g);
                LineArrow line4 = new LineArrow(this.getWidth(), 0, 0, this.getHeight(), Color.MAGENTA, 3);
                line4.draw(g);
                LineArrow line5 = new LineArrow((insets.right + insets.left) / 2, (insets.top + insets.bottom) / 2, 140, 170, Color.BLUE, 3);
                line5.draw(g);
                LineArrow line6 = new LineArrow(this.getWidth() / 2, this.getHeight() / 2, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight() / 2, Color.CYAN, 3);
                line6.draw(g);
            }
        };
        contentPane.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }

    private static final Polygon ARROW_HEAD = new Polygon();

    static {
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(0, 0);
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(-5, -10);
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(5, -10);
    }

    public static class LineArrow {

        private final int x;
        private final int y;
        private final int endX;
        private final int endY;
        private final Color color;
        private final int thickness;

        public LineArrow(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, Color color, int thickness) {
            super();
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.endX = x2;
            this.endY = y2;
            this.color = color;
            this.thickness = thickness;
        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            // Calcula o ângulo da seta.
            double angle = Math.atan2(endY - y, endX - x);

            g2.setColor(color);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));

            // Desenha a linha. Corta 10 pixels na ponta para a ponta não ficar grossa.
            g2.drawLine(x, y, (int) (endX - 10 * Math.cos(angle)), (int) (endY - 10 * Math.sin(angle)));

            // Obtém o AffineTransform original.
            AffineTransform tx1 = g2.getTransform();

            // Cria uma cópia do AffineTransform.
            AffineTransform tx2 = (AffineTransform) tx1.clone();

            // Translada e rotaciona o novo AffineTransform.
            tx2.translate(endX, endY);
            tx2.rotate(angle - Math.PI / 2);

            // Desenha a ponta com o AffineTransform transladado e rotacionado.
            g2.setTransform(tx2);
            g2.fill(ARROW_HEAD);

            // Restaura o AffineTransform original.
            g2.setTransform(tx1);
        }
    }
}
```

Eis como ficou:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Redimensionar funciona como esperado:

[image: Screenshot 2]

O seu problema era que ao acrescentar a borda no `contentPane`, tudo começava a ficar errado porque a borda interferia com o resultado do desenho.

O que fiz para resolver foi basicamente isso:

- Acrescentei mais linhas para testar melhor.
- Mudei a borda de invisível para uma borda amarela.
- Desenhei um retângulo rosa para delimitar claramente o `drawPanel`.
- Não despreze o `AffineTransform` que já vem no `Graphics` resetando ele com o `setToIdentity()`. Ao invés disso, salve o `AffineTransform` original, crie um outro `AffineTransform` novo como cópia, faça nele a translação e a rotação, desenhe com base neste `AffineTransform` depois de colocá-lo no `Graphics2D` e **coloque de volta o `AffineTransform` original.**
- Não tem porque abusar de `create()` e `dispose()`.
- O seu triângulo está errado. A primeira ponta tem uma coordenada Y = 5. Isso significa que ele vai ultrapassar seu alvo em 5 pixels. A ponta tem que ter um Y = 0. Por causa disso, eu mudei o Y dos outros dois vértices de -5 para -10.
- Desenhei a linha 10 pixels mais curta. O motivo disso é porque ela tem uma espessura considerável, enquanto que a seta tem uma ponta aguda. Se desenhar a linha no comprimento completo, a seta ficaria com uma ponta grossa vez que a linha seria desenhada até o seu final. Logo, a solução é diminuir 10 pixels do comprimento da linha uma vez que a seta percorre esses últimos 10 pixels de comprimento. Como a linha pode não ser perfeitamente horizontal ou vertical, uso o seno e o co-seno para saber quanto deve ser cortado em X e em Y, a partir do ângulo que você já calcula com o `atan2`.
- Outras mudanças simples de padronização - colocar `private final` nos campos, fazer a classe interna ser `static`, usar `DrawPanel` ao invés de `drawPanel`, incorporar o `initComponents()` no construtor, deixar o triângulo da ponta como um polígono imutável e reutilizável, etc.

Comment: Eu peguei esse trecho da resposta, nem sabia que esse detalhe do triangulo faria diferença. Mas não entendi aquelas formulas do drawline pra encurtar o tamanho.

Comment: Uma outra dúvida, pro tamanho da seta ser relativa a espessura da linha, eu posso fazer `tx2.scale(thickness)` ou isso não seria suficiente pra manter a proporção?

Comment: @Articuno Se tenho uma linha diagonal em um ângulo x, multiplico o co-seno de x por 10 pixels e tenho a medida do quanto esses 10 pixels na diagonal correspondem a pixels horizontal. Ao fazer isso também com o seno tenho o quanto eles correspondem na vertical. Vamos supor que o ângulo x seja de 30º. Neste caso cos(30º) = 0.866 e sen(30º) = 0.5. Multiplicando ambos por 10 pixels, tenho 8 pixels na horizontal e 5 na vertical. É isso que subtraio do comprimento da linha.

Comment: @Articuno Se você fizer `tx2.scale(thickness)`, você vai é desenhar a ponta com o triplo do tamanho em todas as direções, já que o `thickness` é 3.

Comment: @Articuno Fiz um teste com o `tx2.scale(thickness, thickness);` e com o `thickness` variando de uma linha para outra. O efeito ficou bem legal, mas não acho que seja o que você quer.

Comment: Testei aqui, fica gigante mesmo. Acabei adotando `tx2.scale(thickness/2, thickness/2);`, ao menos a seta fica mais proporcional ao tamanho. Quanto a formula, eu sou péssimo em geometria kkkk vou ler com mais calma seu comentário depois enquanto compilo o código pra entende-lo melhor.

Comment: @Articuno Faça `tx2.scale(thickness / 2.0, thickness / 2.0);` - Porque sem esse `.0`, vai ser divisão inteira e não dar o que você quer. E multiplique aquele `10` que aparece junto com o seno e o co-seno por `thickness / 2.0`.