# Como girar uma seta dentro de um círculo utilizando Java2D?

Tags: java, swing, java2d

Anteriormente, perguntei "[Como desenhar uma seta utilizando Java2D?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244647/28595)" e agora com a seta desenhada corretamente e posicionada dentro do meu círculo, eu gostaria de fazer com que a seta girasse dentro do círculo, de forma que o centro do círculo fosse o referencial fixo de uma das pontas da seta.

Me passaram que, para calcular a rotação, eu precisaria utilizar a fórmula:

> A={x+L×cos(θ),y+L×sin(θ)}

onde `x` e `y` são as coordenadas no novo ponto do giro, `L` seria o tamanho da seta e `θ` seria o angulo do giro.

Apesar de compreender a fórmula, eu não estou sabendo aplicar na minha classe `LineArrow`, até porque eu a desenho baseado em coordenadas, e como ela pode mudar de ângulo, eu não estou sabendo como calcular seu tamanho, independente da posição em que ela estiver no círculo. No exemplo utilizei a posição vertical, mas essa posição poderia ser qualquer uma. E também não sei se ela é a ideal a ser aplicada neste código.

Minha classe `LineArrow` está da seguinte forma:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class LineArrow {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int endX;
    private int endY;
    private Color color;
    private int thickness;
    private static final Polygon ARROW_HEAD = new Polygon();

    static {
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(0, 0);
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(-5, -10);
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(5, -10);
    }

    public LineArrow(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, Color color, int thickness) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.endX = x2;
        this.endY = y2;

        this.color = color;
        this.thickness = thickness;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Calcula o ângulo da seta.
        double angle = Math.atan2(endY - y, endX - x);

        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));

        // Desenha a linha. Corta 10 pixels na ponta para a ponta não ficar
        // grossa.
        g2.drawLine(x, y, (int) (endX - 10 * Math.cos(angle)), (int) (endY - 10 * Math.sin(angle)));

        // Obtém o AffineTransform original.
        AffineTransform tx1 = g2.getTransform();

        // Cria uma cópia do AffineTransform.
        AffineTransform tx2 = (AffineTransform) tx1.clone();

        // Translada e rotaciona o novo AffineTransform.
        tx2.translate(endX, endY);
        tx2.scale(thickness / 2, thickness / 2);
        tx2.rotate(angle - Math.PI / 2);

        // Desenha a ponta com o AffineTransform transladado e rotacionado.
        g2.setTransform(tx2);
        g2.fill(ARROW_HEAD);

        // Restaura o AffineTransform original.
        g2.setTransform(tx1);
    }

    public void spin() {
        // ????
    }
}
```

---

Segue um exemplo compilável:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SpinArrowTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel board;
    private JPanel controlsPane;
    private JButton rotateButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new SpinArrowTest().setVisible(true));
    }

    public SpinArrowTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        this.contentPane = new JPanel();
        this.contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        this.contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(this.contentPane);

        this.board = new Board();

        this.contentPane.add(this.board, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.controlsPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        this.controlsPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 1, 1, 1));

        this.rotateButton = new JButton("Rotate");
        this.rotateButton.addActionListener(e -> {

        });
        this.controlsPane.add(this.rotateButton);

        this.contentPane.add(this.controlsPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
    }
}
```

Classe Painel principal onde ocorrerá a animação e desenho:

```
class Board extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Circle circle;
    private LineArrow line;

    public void spin() {
        line.spin();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        int widthRectangle = getWidth();
        int heightReclangle = getHeight();

        int x, y, diameter;

        if (widthRectangle <= heightReclangle) {
            diameter = widthRectangle;
            y = heightReclangle / 2 - diameter / 2;
            x = 0;
        } else {
            diameter = heightReclangle;
            x = widthRectangle / 2 - diameter / 2;
            y = 0;

        }
        circle = new Circle(x, y, diameter, Color.red);
        circle.draw(g);

        line = new LineArrow(x + diameter / 2, y + diameter / 2, x + diameter / 2, y + diameter, Color.white, 3);
        line.draw(g);
    }
}
```

Classe que representa o circulo:

```
class Circle {

    int x;
    int y;
    int diameter;
    Color color;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int diameter, Color color) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(x, y, color, x + diameter / 2, y + diameter / 2, color.darker()));
        g2.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    }

}
```

Classe que representa a seta que irá girar dentro do circulo

```
class LineArrow {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int endX;
    private int endY;
    private Color color;
    private int thickness;
    private static final Polygon ARROW_HEAD = new Polygon();

    static {
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(0, 0);
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(-5, -10);
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(5, -10);
    }

    public LineArrow(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, Color color, int thickness) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.endX = x2;
        this.endY = y2;

        this.color = color;
        this.thickness = thickness;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Calcula o ângulo da seta.
        double angle = Math.atan2(endY - y, endX - x);

        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));

        // Desenha a linha. Corta 10 pixels na ponta para a ponta não ficar
        // grossa.
        g2.drawLine(x, y, (int) (endX - 10 * Math.cos(angle)), (int) (endY - 10 * Math.sin(angle)));

        // Obtém o AffineTransform original.
        AffineTransform tx1 = g2.getTransform();

        // Cria uma cópia do AffineTransform.
        AffineTransform tx2 = (AffineTransform) tx1.clone();

        // Translada e rotaciona o novo AffineTransform.
        tx2.translate(endX, endY);
        tx2.scale(thickness / 2, thickness / 2);
        tx2.rotate(angle - Math.PI / 2);

        // Desenha a ponta com o AffineTransform transladado e rotacionado.
        g2.setTransform(tx2);
        g2.fill(ARROW_HEAD);

        // Restaura o AffineTransform original.
        g2.setTransform(tx1);
    }

    public void spin() {
        // ????
    }
}
```

O resultado é o da figura abaixo(estático):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você extrai o ângulo a partir das posições das setas e quer rotacionar as posições. Uma abordagem melhor é fazer o contrário: rotacionar o ângulo e a partir do ângulo extrair a posição.

Segue o código completo. Clicar no botão rotate vai girar a seta em 10 graus no sentido horário:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SpinArrowTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(SpinArrowTest::new);
    }

    public SpinArrowTest() {
        setTitle("Clique no botão Rotate");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        Board board = new Board();

        contentPane.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel controlsPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        controlsPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 1, 1, 1));

        JButton rotateButton = new JButton("Rotate");
        rotateButton.addActionListener(e -> board.spin());
        controlsPane.add(rotateButton);

        contentPane.add(controlsPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Board extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private double angleDegrees;

    public Board() {
        angleDegrees = 90;
    }

    public void spin() {
        angleDegrees += 10;
        angleDegrees %= 360;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));

        super.paintComponent(g2);

        int widthRectangle = getWidth();
        int heightReclangle = getHeight();

        int x, y, diameter;

        if (widthRectangle <= heightReclangle) {
            diameter = widthRectangle;
            y = heightReclangle / 2 - diameter / 2;
            x = 0;
        } else {
            diameter = heightReclangle;
            x = widthRectangle / 2 - diameter / 2;
            y = 0;
        }
        Circle circle = new Circle(x, y, diameter, Color.red);
        circle.draw(g2);

        LineArrow line = new LineArrow(x + diameter / 2, y + diameter / 2, angleDegrees, diameter / 2, Color.white, 3, 20);
        line.draw(g2);
    }
}
```

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Circle {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final int diameter;
    private final Color color;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int diameter, Color color) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(x, y, color, x + diameter / 2, y + diameter / 2, color.darker()));
        g2.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    }
}
```

```java
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class LineArrow {

    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final int endX;
    private final int endY;
    private final double angleRadians;
    private final Color color;
    private final int thickness;
    private final double scale;

    private static final int TRIANGLE_LENGTH = 2;
    private static final Polygon ARROW_HEAD = new Polygon();

    static {
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(TRIANGLE_LENGTH, 0);
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(0, -TRIANGLE_LENGTH / 2);
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(0, TRIANGLE_LENGTH / 2);
    }

    public LineArrow(int x, int y, double angleDegrees, int length, Color color, int thickness, int headSize) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
        this.thickness = thickness;

        // Converte o ângulo para radianos.
        this.angleRadians = Math.toRadians(angleDegrees);

        // Calcula a escala a ser aplicada ao desenhar a ponta.
        this.scale = headSize / TRIANGLE_LENGTH;

        // Calcula a posição final da linha de acordo com o ângulo e com o
        // comprimento. Corta do comprimento o tamanho da ponta.
        this.endX = (int) (x + (length - headSize) * Math.cos(angleRadians));
        this.endY = (int) (y + (length - headSize) * Math.sin(angleRadians));
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        // Define a cor e a espessura da linha.
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));

        // Desenha a linha.
        g2.drawLine(x, y, endX, endY);

        // Obtém o AffineTransform original.
        AffineTransform tx1 = g2.getTransform();

        // Cria uma cópia do AffineTransform.
        AffineTransform tx2 = (AffineTransform) tx1.clone();

        // Translada e rotaciona o novo AffineTransform.
        tx2.translate(endX, endY);
        tx2.scale(scale, scale);
        tx2.rotate(angleRadians);

        // Desenha a ponta com o AffineTransform transladado e rotacionado.
        g2.setTransform(tx2);
        g2.fill(ARROW_HEAD);

        // Restaura o AffineTransform original.
        g2.setTransform(tx1);
    }
}
```

Aqui um screenshot após clicar 3 vezes no botão rotate e girar 30 graus:

[image: Screenshot 1]

Funciona perfeitamente se a tela for redimensionada:

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Mudanças que fiz:

- Não use variáveis de instância para aquilo que pode ser feito com variáveis locais.
- Dificilmente você vai querer usar a visibilidade de pacote. Então não esqueça os modificadores `private`.
- Fiz as classes `Circle` e `SpinArrow` serem imutáveis. Lidar com classes imutáveis costuma ser mais simples do que com classes mutáveis. O ângulo, que é mutável, fica na classe `Board`.
- Como o `SpinArrow` é imutável, ele não tem um método `spin()`. O que ocorre é que esse objeto tem uma vida curta, sendo instanciado dentro do método `paintComponent(Graphics)` de `Board` já com os seus valores definitivos e sendo descartado para o coletor de lixo nesse mesmo método.
- Desacoplei o tamanho da ponta da espessura da linha.
- Sabe aquele "`- Math.PI / 2`" no `rotate`? Aquilo é uma gambiarra. O motivo é que o triângulo estava definido voltado para baixo quando deveria estar para a direita, e essa rotação em 90 graus (π / 2) conserta isso. O melhor seria já definir ele voltado para o lado certo para não precisar girar ele em 90 graus depois, e foi isso o que fiz. Desculpe-me não ter percebido isso ontem.
- Na sua pergunta anterior eu tinha definido o triângulo com o tamanho 10 porque ele teria 10 pixels de tamanho. Agora, que o tamanho dele pode ser especificado pela classe `Board` (que inclusive está usando 20 pixels), ele usa uma escala independente dos pixels. A escala que ele usa é duas unidades de comprimento e uma unidade de largura para cada lado.
- Antes, ele calculava a posição final da linha (`endX` e `endY`) ao pegar a posição final desejada e subtrair o comprimento da seta. E então a seta era desenhada com a ponta na posição desejada (por isso que um dos vértices do triângulo estava em (0, 0)). Agora, como o `endX` e o `endY` são o final do comprimento da linha sem ponta, então o triângulo é definido para ser desenhado a partir dessa posição, e por isso o ponto (0, 0) agora está na base.
- Observe que o `endX` e o `endY` é definido com o sendo e o co-seno do ângulo dado.
- Acrescentei antialiasing no `Board`. Tanto o círculo quanto a seta ficam bem melhores com isso.

Comment: Essa abordagem dispensa o uso da fórmula da pergunta, menos matematica! (hehe

Comment: O mais interessante é que achei que iria ter que sacrificar a responsividade, mas dessa forma, permanece tudo se redimensionando e mantendo o aspecto. E não tive que me preocupar em deduzir o tamanho da `LineArrow` para calcular o angulo.

Comment: Uma duvida: Por "imutável", você quer dizer que as classes que representam as duas figuras não podem ter nada alterado após serem instanciadas, exceto o angulo no caso da classe LineArrow?

Comment: @Articuno Uma classe imutável, é que nem a `java.lang.String` ou a `java.lang.Integer`. Os valores de todas variáveis de instância são definidos unicamente no construtor e não mudam jamais.

Comment: @Articuno Nem o ângulo do `LineArrow` pode ser alterado. O que ocorre é que uma nova instância de `LineArrow` com um ângulo diferente é criada no `Board`.

Comment: To vendo que você criou uma instancia de `Graphics2D` no Board para aplicar o anti-aliasing, mas LineArrow e Circle continuam recebendo `Graphics` e fazendo esse mesmo casting dentro delas. Se eu alterar as duas classes para receber o Graphics2D que você já cria no Board seria uma otimização ou é indiferente?

Comment: @Articuno Na verdade eu não criei uma instância, apenas usei um cast. É o mesmo objeto (ou seja, `g == g2`). Se quiser, pode mudar o tipo do parâmetro do `Circle` e do `LineArrow` para `Graphics2D` para ficar mais simples. Não chamaria isso de otimização, e sim de simplificação. Aliás, vou editar a resposta para fazer exatamente isso.

Answer (score 3):

Para aplicar a fórmula

```
A={x+L×cos(θ),y+L×sin(θ)}
```

ao seu caso, A é o ponto fim da reta. Assim:

```
angle += 0.2;
endX = (int) (x+length*Math.cos(angle));
endY = (int) (y+length*Math.sin(angle));
```

`angle` é o tanto que você quer que a reta "pule" a cada "rotate".

Código:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class SpinArrowTest extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel board;
    private JPanel controlsPane;
    private JButton rotateButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new SpinArrowTest().setVisible(true));
    }

    public SpinArrowTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        this.contentPane = new JPanel();
        this.contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        this.contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(this.contentPane);

        this.board = new Board();

        this.contentPane.add(this.board, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.controlsPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
        this.controlsPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 1, 1, 1));

        this.rotateButton = new JButton("Rotate");
        this.rotateButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            ((Board)board).spin();
        });
        this.controlsPane.add(this.rotateButton);

        this.contentPane.add(this.controlsPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();
        ((Board)board).init();
    }
}

// painel principal onde ocorrerá a animação e desenho

class Board extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Circle circle;
    private LineArrow line;
    int widthRectangle;
    int heightReclangle;

    int x, y, diameter;

    public void init(){
        int widthRectangle = getWidth();
        int heightReclangle = getHeight();
        if (widthRectangle <= heightReclangle) {
            diameter = widthRectangle;
            y = heightReclangle / 2 - diameter / 2;
            x = 0;
        } else {
            diameter = heightReclangle;
            x = widthRectangle / 2 - diameter / 2;
            y = 0;

        }
        circle = new Circle(x, y, diameter, Color.red);
        line = new LineArrow(x + diameter / 2, y + diameter / 2, x + diameter, y  + diameter / 2, Color.white, 3);
    }
    public void spin() {
        line.spin();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        circle.draw(g);
        line.draw(g);
    }


}

// CLASSE QUE REPRESENTA O CIRCULO

class Circle {

    int x;
    int y;
    int diameter;
    Color color;

    public Circle(int x, int y, int diameter, Color color) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.diameter = diameter;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(x, y, color, x + diameter / 2, y + diameter / 2, color.darker()));
        g2.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    }

}

// CLASSE QUE REPRESENTA A SETA QUE IRÁ GIRAR DENTRO DO CIRCULO

class LineArrow {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int endX;
    private int endY;
    private double length;
    private double angle;
    private Color color;
    private int thickness;
    private static final Polygon ARROW_HEAD = new Polygon();

    static {
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(0, 0);
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(-5, -10);
        ARROW_HEAD.addPoint(5, -10);
    }

    public LineArrow(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, Color color, int thickness) {
        super();
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.endX = x2;
        this.endY = y2;
        angle = Math.atan2(endY - y, endX - x);

        this.color = color;
        this.thickness = thickness;

        int a = endX-x;
        int b = endY-y;
        length = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Calcula o ângulo da seta.
        double angle = Math.atan2(endY - y, endX - x);

        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(thickness));

        // Desenha a linha. Corta 10 pixels na ponta para a ponta não ficar
        // grossa.
        g2.drawLine(x, y, (int) (endX - 10 * Math.cos(angle)), (int) (endY - 10 * Math.sin(angle)));

        // Obtém o AffineTransform original.
        AffineTransform tx1 = g2.getTransform();

        // Cria uma cópia do AffineTransform.
        AffineTransform tx2 = (AffineTransform) tx1.clone();

        // Translada e rotaciona o novo AffineTransform.
        tx2.translate(endX, endY);
        tx2.scale(thickness / 2, thickness / 2);
        tx2.rotate(angle - Math.PI / 2);

        // Desenha a ponta com o AffineTransform transladado e rotacionado.
        g2.setTransform(tx2);
        g2.fill(ARROW_HEAD);

        // Restaura o AffineTransform original.
        g2.setTransform(tx1);


    }

    public void spin() {
        angle += 0.2;
        endX = (int) (x+length*Math.cos(angle));
        endY = (int) (y+length*Math.sin(angle));
    }
}
```

P.s.: não tenho muito experiência com swing então não sei se o `init();` depois do `pack()` é a melhor maneira de inicializar os valores de Board. Mas tem que ser separado do `spin()`.

Comment: Já fiz isso, e não funciona. Alias, length não é somente a distancia entre pontos y, uma vez que se a a reta estiver na horizontal, essa conta vai falhar

Comment: Oi Articuno. Eu copiei e colei o código acima de uma classe que eu executei e faz a rotação. Pode copiar e colar (o código completo), e confiar =D

Comment: Como disse o length nem sempre é a diferença entre os pontos y's. Iniciei a seta em vertical apenas para demonstração, não quer dizer que ela sempre vai iniciar nessa posição.

Comment: Ah sim, isso está no meu comentário: `length = endY - y; // n deve pegar assim, só tirando vantagem de que é uma reta na vertical`. Sua dúvida parecia ser sobre como aplicar a fórmula de rotação.

Comment: A distância deve ser calculada usando o bom e velho de pitágoras. Quando tiver um tempo posso ver isso.

Comment: Então, mas a duvida é não só como girar, mas como saber calcular o tamanho independente da posição da seta. Assim pouco importará como eu inicializo ela, o angulo sempre será calculado corretamente. Outro detalhe, não posso dar init depois do pack(), isso pode me dar problemas com resizing e com o repaint :/

Comment: O ângulo sempre é calculado corretamente. A única variável é como pegar `length`.

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta para que length seja calculado independente de onde começa a reta (note que agora, por exemplo, ela começa na horizontal).

Comment: Uma duvida, porque `endX = (int)(x+length*Math.cos(angle));endY = (int) (y+length*Math.sin(angle));` e não `endX = (int) (endX+length*Math.cos(angle)); endY = (int) (endY+length*Math.sin(angle));`? Eu havia entendido que os pontos da formula deveriam ser os que se moviam, então, somente os da ponta.

Comment: Os pontos finais da reta são os que se movem. O local deles é calculado a partir do ponto fixo (x,y), o centro do círculo, e length o tamanho da reta. Eu acho fácil de pensar em length como sendo uma "vareta" com uma ponta fixa em (x,y) e rodando angle. E a fórmula diz onde deve ir a outra ponta da vareta (endX, endY).

Comment: maria agradeço pela sua prestatividade, os calculos realmente funcionaram, mas agora minha tela não é mais adaptativa. Creio que o motivo seja esse init() após o pack(). Se você testar o exemplo da pergunta, o circulo e a seta se adaptavam conforme se redimensionasse pra qualquer lado. agora eles ficam fixos.