# Detectar sobreposição de figuras após arrastar com o mouse

Tags: java, swing, java2d

Desenhei quatro figuras com o Graphics 2D (dois triângulos grandes e dois médios), sendo duas fixas (1 triângulo médio e um 1 triângulo grande) e 2 para movimentação (1 triângulo médio e 1 triângulo grande).

Ao mover a figura, preciso detectar se ela foi arrastada e solta na sua figura correspondente. Por exemplo, se o triângulo Grande foi arrastado e solto no triângulo Grande e o médio a mesma coisa.

Segue meu código:

```
public class Teste2 extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private Polygon[] polygons = {};
    private Polygon[] polygons2 = {};
    private Point ultimo = null;
    private Polygon selecionado = null;

    public Teste2() {
        polygons = new Polygon[2];
        polygons2 = new Polygon[2];
        this.mover();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fillPolygon(polygons[0]);

        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillPolygon(polygons[1]);

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.drawPolygon(polygons2[0]);

        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawPolygon(polygons2[1]);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public void trianguloGrande1() {
        int x[] = {90, 90, 392};
        int y[] = {512, 248, 512};
        polygons2[0] = new Polygon(x, y, 3);
    }

    public void trianguloMedio1() {
        int x[] = {245, 90, 395};
        int y[] = {110, 242, 242};
        polygons2[1] = new Polygon(x, y, 3);
    }

    public void trianguloGrande2() {
        int x[] = {630, 630, 933};
        int y[] = {283, 19, 283};
        polygons[0] = new Polygon(x, y, 3);
    }

    public void trianguloMedio2() {
        int x[] = {1152, 1000, 1305};
        int y[] = {86, 219, 219};
        polygons[1] = new Polygon(x, y, 3);
    }

    public Polygon[] getPolygons() {
        return polygons;
    }

    public void setPolygons(Polygon[] polygons) {
        this.polygons = polygons;
    }

    public Polygon[] getPolygons2() {
        return polygons;
    }

    public void setPolygons2(Polygon[] polygons2) {
        this.polygons2 = polygons2;
    }

    private void mover() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                onMouseDown(e);
                Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                if (e.isMetaDown()) {
                    polygons[0].contains(x, y);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                onMouseDragged(e);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onMouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
        ultimo = e.getPoint();
        for (Polygon polygon : polygons) {
            if (polygon.contains(ultimo)) {
                selecionado = polygon;
                return;
            }
        }
        selecionado = null;
    }

    protected void onMouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Point now = e.getPoint();
        if (ultimo != null) {
            int xt = now.x - ultimo.x;
            int yt = now.y - ultimo.y;
            if (selecionado != null) {
                selecionado.translate(xt, yt);
                repaint();
            }
            ultimo = now;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Teste");
                Teste2 teste2 = new Teste2();

                jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                jFrame.getContentPane().add(teste2);
                jFrame.pack();
                jFrame.setResizable(false);
                jFrame.setVisible(true);
                jFrame.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

                teste2.trianguloGrande1();
                teste2.trianguloGrande2();
                teste2.trianguloMedio1();
                teste2.trianguloMedio2();
                teste2.setPolygons(teste2.polygons);
                teste2.setPolygons2(teste2.polygons2);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Você precisaria criar um JPanel para cada quadrado, e capturar os eventos do JPanel

Comment: Posso sugerir uma abordagem diferente, semelhante a que usei [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244909/28595) ?

Comment: Pode sim, @Articuno...

Comment: Seu código é estatico, não há movimento ou animacao. Você quer é detectar colisão?

Comment: Tipo, eu queria saber se o triângulo que será colocado sobre o outro  (por exemplo: o triângulo Grande), é de fato um Triângulo Grande (o que seria correto) ou um triângulo médio (o que estaria errado, nesse caso)...

Comment: O problema é que seu codigo está bastante incompleto(apesar de reproduzivel), sugerir algo desse tipo seria amplo demais, você não implementou nada de movimento nem de clique e arraste. A pergunta fica sem sentido pois supoe-se que isso já estaria implementado e que sua duvida era somente detectar sobreposicao.

Comment: Eu tô implementando essa parte de arrastar e clicar... Minha dúvida maior mesmo, é na questão da sobreposição... Peço desculpas se não soube expressar

Comment: Entendo, então o melhor seria adicionar a implementaçao de arrastar primeiro e depois se preocupar com sobreposicao. Sem essa implementação, não tem como sugerir nada, pois teriamos que criar essa implementação, que foge completamente da duvida.

Comment: Atualizei o código... @Articuno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A solução abaixo subtende-se que o que é pretendido é detectar quando os triângulos preenchidos estarão sobrepostos nos triângulos apenas contornados por completo.

Detectar sobreposição completa, tendo em vista que os triângulos tem tamanhos bem parecidos, pode ser feita usando-se o método `contains()` da classe [`Retangle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html), onde no exemplo abaixo:

```
retanguloA.contains(retanguloB);
```

verificamos se o `retanguloA` contém o `retanguloeB` por completo.

O melhor momento para verificar isso é quando o arraste do objeto for concluido, 
ou seja, quando o botão do mouse for liberado, e o método que é chamado quando isso ocorre é o [`mouseReleased()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseReleased-java.awt.event.MouseEvent-). É dentro dele que vamos verificar se os triângulos preenchidos estão contidos nos fixos:

```
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        if(fixedPolygons[0].getBounds().contains(polygons[0].getBounds())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Triangulos grandes sincronizados");
        }

        if(fixedPolygons[1].getBounds().contains(polygons[1].getBounds())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Triangulos medios sincronizados");
        }
    }
```

O método [`getBounds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#getBounds--) retorna um retângulo cuja a área é o minimo possível para envolver por completo o polígono criado. Porém, eu tive que reduzir levemente os triângulos móveis para funcionar melhor.

Fiz uma pequena modificação no nome de algumas variáveis, pois estava difícil identificar de qual array determinado triangulo fazia parte, por isso é importante fornecer nomes que façam sentido para o uso dela, neste caso, eu renomeei o array para `fixedPolygons`.

O código completo com as modificações ficou assim:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MousetriangulosTest extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    private Polygon[] polygons = {};
    private Polygon[] fixedPolygons = {};
    private Point ultimo = null;
    private Polygon selecionado = null;

    public MousetriangulosTest() {
        polygons = new Polygon[2];
        fixedPolygons = new Polygon[2];
        this.mover();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fillPolygon(polygons[0]);

        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillPolygon(polygons[1]);

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.drawPolygon(fixedPolygons[0]);

        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.drawPolygon(fixedPolygons[1]);
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public void trianguloGrande1() {
        int x[] = {90, 90, 392};
        int y[] = {512, 248, 512};
        fixedPolygons[0] = new Polygon(x, y, 3);
    }

    public void trianguloMedio1() {
        int x[] = {245, 90, 395};
        int y[] = {110, 242, 242};
        fixedPolygons[1] = new Polygon(x, y, 3);
    }

    public void trianguloGrande2() {
        int x[] = {630, 630, 923};
        int y[] = {273, 19, 273};
        polygons[0] = new Polygon(x, y, 3);
    }

    public void trianguloMedio2() {
        int x[] = {1152, 1000, 1295};
        int y[] = {86, 209, 209};
        polygons[1] = new Polygon(x, y, 3);
    }

    public Polygon[] getPolygons() {
        return polygons;
    }

    public void setPolygons(Polygon[] polygons) {
        this.polygons = polygons;
    }

    public Polygon[] getPolygons2() {
        return polygons;
    }

    public void setPolygons2(Polygon[] polygons2) {
        this.fixedPolygons = polygons2;
    }

    private void mover() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                onMouseDown(e);
                Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
                int x = e.getX();
                int y = e.getY();
                if (e.isMetaDown()) {
                    polygons[0].contains(x, y);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                if(fixedPolygons[0].getBounds().contains(polygons[0].getBounds())) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Triangulos grandes sincronizados");
                }

                if(fixedPolygons[1].getBounds().contains(polygons[1].getBounds())) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Triangulos medios sincronizados");
                }
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                onMouseDragged(e);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onMouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
        ultimo = e.getPoint();
        for (Polygon polygon : polygons) {
            if (polygon.contains(ultimo)) {
                selecionado = polygon;
                return;
            }
        }
        selecionado = null;
    }

    protected void onMouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Point now = e.getPoint();
        if (ultimo != null) {
            int xt = now.x - ultimo.x;
            int yt = now.y - ultimo.y;
            if (selecionado != null) {
                selecionado.translate(xt, yt);
                repaint();
            }
            ultimo = now;
        }   
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Teste");
                MousetriangulosTest teste2 = new MousetriangulosTest();

                jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                jFrame.getContentPane().add(teste2);
                jFrame.pack();
                jFrame.setResizable(false);
                jFrame.setVisible(true);
                jFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

                teste2.trianguloGrande1();
                teste2.trianguloGrande2();
                teste2.trianguloMedio1();
                teste2.trianguloMedio2();
                teste2.setPolygons(teste2.polygons);
                teste2.setPolygons2(teste2.fixedPolygons);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Em execução, vai ocorrer isso:

[image: triangulos grandes sobrepostos]

[image: triangulos medios sobrepostos]

Claro que, ao executar, você vai notar que se tentar sobrepor o triangulo maior com o menor já sobreposto, ou vice-versa, a mensagem vai ficar repetindo cada vez que soltar o mouse. Mas isso eu deixei propositalmente para que você decida o que deverá ocorrer após as sobreposições.

Comment: Muitooo obrigadooo! Você me ajudou muito mesmoooo! Vlw mesmoooo!!